# C# Not getting the reference to System.Runtime.Serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, dll, .net-core

This is the error that I am getting building a .NET Core console app:

> Error CS034 The type or name of the 'Serialization' namespace does not
>   exist in the 'System.Runtime' namespace (are any assembly references
>   missing?)

The thing is when I open the program.cs with the visual studio i dont get any errors but when I open the Application yes.

Comment: You are getting a run-time error.  Can you launch your app in debug mode and see where it throws the exception?

Comment: That's what it shows: The application to execute doesnt exists: C:\Users\User\Desktop\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\ConsoleApp.dll

Comment: From your comment (but not your question) it appears you may be using .Net Core.  Can you confirm?  If so, is this your problem?  [System.Runtime.Serialization doesn't exist in .NET Core, but is documented](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/319)

Comment: Yes, im using .Net Core and that's indeed my problem.